# Convert .xlsb to .xlsx - Multi-sheet Microsoft Excel File

Tags: python

I have a multi-sheet excel file saved in a .xlsb format that I wish to covert to .xlsx to utilize the openpyxl library - code already written to support the same workbook that used to be .xlsx until macro-enabled, and wouldn't save in .xlsm.

I have managed to convert from .xlsb to .csv, but cannot convert any further and have hit roadblocks with various libraries due to various formatting errors.

As my file has multiple sheets (all tables) I only need to copy and paste the text on every sheet (keeping the sheet names) and get it to a .xlsx format.

For simplicity sake, imagine all I need to do is: get sheet names, access a sheet, determine max row/column, loop: copy and paste cell values, write to .xlsx with sheet name. With the starting file being .xlsb.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Just tested this.

Pandas now supports xlsb and can open these files using Glen Thompson's method described in [Read XLSB File in Pandas Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019778/read-xlsb-file-in-pandas-python):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xlsb', engine='pyxlsb')
```

And then you could use:

```
df.to_excel('path_to_file.xlsx')
```

Make sure you pip install `pyxlsb`, `openpyxl` and `xlrd`, I always forget.

Answer (score 2):

Try the latest `xlsb2xlsx` package on PyPI:

```
pip install xlsb2xlsx
python -m xlsb2xlsx /filepath_with_xlsb_file
```

See https://pypi.org/project/xlsb2xlsx/ for more info.

Comment: Note that does use the Aspose library but this saved me a lot of problems

Answer (score 0):

### Office answer

**Newer** version of Microsoft Office Excel, OpenOffice Calc or LibreOffice Calc can read `xlsb`.

So you'll just need to open the file in one of those and export it to `xlsx`

[Reference](https://www.lifewire.com/xlsb-file-2622534)

### Python answer

### CSV -> xlsx

This can be done easily with `pandas`, a python package.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file.csv")
df.to_excel("/path/to/result.xlsx")
```

### xlsb -> xlsx

[As mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019778/read-xlsb-file-in-pandas-python), pandas `1.0.0` added the support for binary excel files.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("/path/to/file.xlsb", engine="pyxlsb")
df.to_excel("/path/to/result.xlsx")
```

In order to use it you must upgrade `pandas`, and install `pyxlsb` and 'openpyxl':

```sh
pip install pandas --upgrade
pip install pyxlsb
```

(this assumes the use of python 3 since python 2 reached [End of Life](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/))

If you need more control over the file you can directly use [`pyxlsb`](https://pypi.org/project/pyxlsb/)

Comment: pyxlsb has an "extemely limited" functionality.  :(
https://github.com/willtrnr/pyxlsb

Answer (score 0):

I got copy code to test run,but that return error,above error .
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\l84193928\Desktop\test.xlsb', engine='pyxlsb')

D:\Users\l84193928\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
176                 else:
177                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 178             return func(*args, **kwargs)
179         return wrapper
180     return _deprecate_kwarg

D:\Users\l84193928\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
176                 else:
177                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 178             return func(*args, **kwargs)
179         return wrapper
180     return _deprecate_kwarg

D:\Users\l84193928\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, **kwds)
305
306     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 307         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
308
309     return io.parse(

D:\Users\l84193928\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in **init**(self, io, **kwds)
367
368         if engine is not None and engine != 'xlrd':
--> 369             raise ValueError("Unknown engine: {engine}".format(engine=engine))
370
371         # If io is a url, want to keep the data as bytes so can't pass

ValueError: Unknown engine: pyxlsb

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Answer (score -1):

We can use Pandas, but we can lose some information from .xlsb (such as color, border, images, etc) Best way to convert .xlsb to .xlsx format without losing information is using **aspose-cells** Module in Python, it uses java in backend.
We can install this module using **pip install aspose-cells**

```
# Use Aspose.Cells for Python via Java
# Install java runtime 64 bit
import jpype
import asposecells
jpype.startJVM()
from asposecells.api import *

# Open an excel file
workbook = Workbook(r"xlsb_filepath.xlsb")
workbook.save(r"xlsx_filepath.xlsx")
```

reference from:

[https://blog.aspose.com/2021/05/28/convert-excel-to-image-in-python/#:~:text=Python%20Excel%20to%20Image%20Converter%20API%20In%20order,can%20install%20the%20API%20using%20the%20following%20command](https://blog.aspose.com/2021/05/28/convert-excel-to-image-in-python/#:%7E:text=Python%20Excel%20to%20Image%20Converter%20API%20In%20order,can%20install%20the%20API%20using%20the%20following%20command).

https://products.aspose.com/cells/cpp/conversion/xlsb-to-xlsx/