# Dealing with XSLB Excel files and download on sharepoint

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, sharepoint, xlsb

I connected to SharePoint to my Cloud Environment Directory and downloaded it to my current directory.

```
file_url = """/sites/XXXXXX/Shared%20Documents/General/new_name/train_data.xlsx"""

response = File.open_binary(ctx, file_url)
response.raise_for_status()

import pathlib

ROOT_DIR = pathlib.Path().resolve()
download_file_path = ROOT_DIR / "download_test.xlsb"


response.raise_for_status() # 200 is the response code, so it downloaded successfully


with open(download_file_path, "wb") as local_file: # This is the part where I think needs to be changed
    local_file.write(response.content)
```

I cannot open the downloaded file on Excel as it says it "format or extension is not valid".

I used the following to read the downloaded Excel file ending with .xlsb extension for analysis in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_excel("download_test.xlsb", engine='pyxlsb')
```

I get the following error:

```
usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in open(self, name, mode, pwd, force_zip64)
   1373         else:
   1374             # Get info object for name
-> 1375             zinfo = self.getinfo(name)
   1376 
   1377         if mode == 'w':

/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py in getinfo(self, name)
   1302         if info is None:
   1303             raise KeyError(
-> 1304                 'There is no item named %r in the archive' % name)
   1305 
   1306         return info

KeyError: "There is no item named 'xl/_rels/workbook.bin.rels' in the archive"
```

I already searched for similar questions
[Read XLSB File in Pandas Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019778/read-xlsb-file-in-pandas-python)
[Convert .xlsb to .xlsx - Multi-sheet Microsoft Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60036199/convert-xlsb-to-xlsx-multi-sheet-microsoft-excel-file)

Without success. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the latest xlsb2xlsx package on PyPI:

```
pip install xlsb2xlsx
python -m xlsb2xlsx /directory_with_xlsb_file
```

Then you can use `pandas` with something like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('your_filepath.xlsx')
```

And work with the `df` object from there.

See https://pypi.org/project/xlsb2xlsx/ for more info.