# How do I add xlsb files to the catalog in Kedro?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, kedro

1.I am using this code in catalog.yml file

```
equipment_data:
  type: pandas.ExcelDataSet
  filepath: data\01_raw\Equipment Profile.xlsb
  layer: raw
```

2. getting error after executing kedro run command.

`
kedro.io.core.DataSetError: Failed while loading data from data set ExcelDataSet(filepath=C:/Users/Akshay Salvi/Desktop/Bizmetrics/kedro-environment/petrocaeRepo/data/01_raw/2. Cycle data (per trip)-20210113T042557Z-001/2. Cycle data (per trip)/CycleData,2020.xlsb, load_args={'engine': xlrd}, protocol=file, save_args={'index': False}, writer_args={'engine': xlsxwriter}).

Excel 2007 xlsb file; not supported
`

Comment: I don't think the ExcelDataSet supports xlsb. Maybe write a custom dataset?

Answer (score 1):

So the `pandas.ExcelDataset` simply calls `pandas` underneath so hopefully you can have luck following [this example from another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60019546/2010808) where the engine (provided by `pip install pyxlsb` installing another package) is used to parse it and simply provide the `engine` parameter as `load_args` in your YAML catalog.