# Read multiple XLSB files in pandas python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsb

I´m starting on this and i need to read multiple **.xlsb** files . All files are found in the same directory. I need to take one specific sheet and create a dataframe.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read XLSB File in Pandas Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45019778/read-xlsb-file-in-pandas-python)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to extract information from 1000 .xlsb excel files. All solutions that i found solve the problem but with .xlsx extension